# iOS app to allow me to print to a wireless printer

Tags: gratis, ios, printing

I am look for an iOS app to let me print documents from all the apps on my iPad and iPhone.

I know a lot of these apps exist but I don't know which one to use, hence I need a recommendation.

I want the following features:

- free
- print, **directly**, to a standard wireless printer (not airprint)
- allow me to choose the range of pages to print
- allow me to choose something like 'fast draft' (low quality, fast print)
- be as easy to use as possible
- runs on iOS 8, iPad **and** iPhone
- not depend on a computer to be a 'middle-man'
- print PDFs, PPTs, DOCs, etc...

I do not need to print photos (although that would be a nice feature).

Comment: I'm not using iOS (hence I cannot give a "valid answer"), but a [quick Google-Fu](https://www.google.com/search?q=print+from+ios) brought up an article on [How to: Print from iOS to a non-AirPrint printer](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2013/01/how-to-print-from-ios-to-a-non-airprint-printer.html), introducing several solutions – might be worth a look.

Comment: @Izzy Sorry for the delay I didn't get a notification - looks like none of them are free that don't have pc-side programs needed. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for a long time, I'm using Printer Pro from Readdle. There is also a free version available. And it has a assistent which offers your AirPrint *and* wireless/network printers available in your network:

https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/printer-pro-dokumente-mails/id393313223